# ld: library not found for -lcrt1.3.1.o clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: objective-c

im trying to run an application on a device, but its giving me the error above, i searched for answers , but didnt find a solution,
no pods are used in this project, when trying to run it on a device, this error is been displayed:

```
Ld /Users/macuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ActN-bjtxkfskskvorugakawqftsijcrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ActN.app/ActN normal armv7
    cd /Volumes/Untitled/ActN
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=4.3
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.3.sdk -L/Users/macuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ActN-bjtxkfskskvorugakawqftsijcrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Volumes/Untitled/ActN -F/Users/macuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ActN-bjtxkfskskvorugakawqftsijcrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/macuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ActN-bjtxkfskskvorugakawqftsijcrs/Build/Intermediates/ActN.build/Debug-iphoneos/ActN.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ActN.LinkFileList -miphoneos-version-min=4.3 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/macuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ActN-bjtxkfskskvorugakawqftsijcrs/Build/Intermediates/ActN.build/Debug-iphoneos/ActN.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ActN_lto.o -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fobjc-link-runtime -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreData -lsqlite3 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/macuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ActN-bjtxkfskskvorugakawqftsijcrs/Build/Intermediates/ActN.build/Debug-iphoneos/ActN.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ActN_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/macuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ActN-bjtxkfskskvorugakawqftsijcrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ActN.app/ActN

ld: library not found for -lcrt1.3.1.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be addressed by using a later min deploy version. I updated a project file to use Target->Deployment Target = 9.0 so that iOS 9 was the min deploy target and that fixed the linker error for me in Xcode.